# SSIS: How to use data from dataflow task in script task?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, ssis

Is there any way out there in SSIS, through which I can be able to get data first, and, then use that data inside my Script Task to generate a sqlite file.

Comment: Could you elaborate better your question? You can get data in SSIS from many sources easily and use it inside an script task. What's the problem?

Comment: Well, here is my requirement. I need to get data from sql server and convert it to sqlite file. What should be an ideal way to proceed in SSIS for this requirement?

Comment: Does [this help](http://mickeystuewe.com/2014/08/20/sql-server-data-transferred-to-a-sqlite-database-using-ssis/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OLE DB Connection and an OLE DB Source together to pull data out from SQL Server. Add an script task, configure it as a destination task,set the input columns an ad the code necessary to fill your sqlite tables.

Comment: Oscar, Can you recommend me an example which relates to your solution

Comment: No, I don't know about any example or tutorial with exactly this solution. Do you have any specific doubt about it, or in general about ssis?

Comment: Yeah, I have like 20 million records in a table in Sql Server.........So, I am thinking of a faster way to convert table into sqlite db........And, related to your solution how can I configure script task as destination task..........

Comment: Here's what I've done......Created a dataflow task......On, double clicking dataflow task, I have created ado net source and ado net destination.....Ado net soure will fetch all the records from a specific table in sql server db........Ado net destination is having connection manager as sqlite data provide......And in the table section i have created a new table named "temp"......When I ran this task, it gave me error